# Import Python class into another folder inside a Package

Tags: python, import, package

I'm trying to import a class (that is inside an specific folder) into another class inside my package, but I got:

> No module named Folder'X'

This is the structure of my project:

```
-project
  |-Sources
    |-Folder1
      |- class1.py
      |- class2.py
    |-Folder2
      |- class3.py
      |- class4.py
  |-__init__.py
```

An this is how I'm doing so far:

--> In class1.py:

```
import Sources.Folder2.class3
class class1(object):
   ...
```

--> In __init__.py:

```
import Sources.Folder1.class1
if __name__ == '__main__':
   ...
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
I found similar questions but I couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be solved just adding an empty `__init__.py` to each folder (if not present)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that it comes from the fact that you need at least an empty **init**.py file in all of your sub-directories.